# Simultaneous parsing, python

Tags: python, multithreading, parsing

I have a python program that sequentially parses through 30,000+ files.

Is there a way I could break this up into multiple threads (is this the correct terminology?)
and parse through chunks of that file at the same time. Say having 30 algorithms parsing through 1000 files each.

Comment: Threading in python will net you no positive gains because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) unless you go to lengths to release it manually, and that will complicate your code.  The `multiprocessing` module may prove useful in processing the data in chunks on separate processors on your machine, but we'd need to see code to make better suggestions.

Comment: Using threads you will not gain *anything*. You'll only slow down the processing. If you want to do parallel computations then you want to use multiple computations. Check [`multiprocessing.Pool.map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) for an easy way to apply some processing step to a sequence of tasks.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the GIL applies only if you're using standard Python -- several alternate implementations of Python don't have that limitation, and might be worth investigating.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: Nonsense. If your code is I/O-bound, the GIL doesn't stop you from benefiting from threading. It's only for CPU-bound code.

Comment: So basically, if I where to thread it, it wouldn't run any faster. Because it would take longer to run each individual thread than the comparable block would take to run in the un-threaded program?

@abarnert my program is I/O-bound as its parsing and returning data, so is the `multiprocessing` module where I should look for answers?

Comment: @myacobucci: If your code spends more time reading files than doing CPU work like parsing strings, it _will_ run faster with threads. If your code spends most of its time doing CPU work, it _won't_.

Comment: @myacobucci: You've got it backward. I/O-bound means you _can_ use threads, not that you _can't_ use threads. But be careful—it's easy to guess wrong about how much CPU your program uses. Fortunately, it's easy to test—you can profile it with threads vs. processes (as long as you've designed it so that it's easy to switch back and forth), or watch how much CPU usage it takes up while running (if it's 100% of one core and 0% of the others, it's probably CPU-bound), etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is easy.

You can create 30 threads explicitly and give each of them 1000 filenames.

But, even simpler, you can create a pool of 30 threads and have them service a thread with 30000 filenames. That gives you automatic load balancing—if some of the files are much bigger than others, you won't have one thread finishing when another one's only 10% done.

The [`concurrent.futures`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) module gives you a nice way to execute tasks in parallel (including passing arguments to the tasks and receiving results, or even exceptions if you want). If you're using Python 2.x or 3.1, you will need to install the backport [`futures`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures). Then you just do this:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    results = executor.map(parse_file, filenames)
```

---

Now, 30 workers is probably way too many. You'll overwhelm the hard drive and its drivers and end up having most of your threads waiting for the disk to seek. But a small number may be worth doing. And it's ridiculously easy to tweak `max_workers` and test the timing and see where the sweet spot is for your system.

---

If your code is doing more CPU work than I/O work—that is, it spends more time parsing strings and building complicated structures and the like than it does reading from the disk—then threads won't help, at least in CPython, because of the Global Interpreter Lock. But you can solve that by using processes.

From a code point of view, this is trivial: just change `ThreadPoolExecutor` to `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

However, if you're returning large or complex data structures, the time spent serializing them across the process boundary may eat into, or even overwhelm, your savings. If that's the case, you can sometimes improve things by batching up larger jobs:

```
def parse_files(filenames):
    return [parse_file(filename) for filename in filenames]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    results = executor.map(parse_files, grouper(10, filenames))
```

But sometimes you probably need to drop to a lower level and use the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) module, which has features like inter-process memory sharing.

---

If you can't/don't want to use `futures`, 2.6+ have [`multiprocessing.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) for a plain processor pool, and a thread pool with the same interface under the name `multiprocessing.ThreadPool` (not documented) or `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` (documented but ugly).

In a trivial case like this, there's really no difference between a plain pool and an executor. And, as mentioned above, in very complicated cases, `multiprocessing` lets you get under the hood. In the middle, `futures` is often simpler. But it's worth learning both.